# Popover Does Not Display When Opened

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I set up a basic example with Ionic Popover. However, when I open the popover, the opacity stays at zero, preventing the popover from showing. I know the method `openPopover` is called because I receive the `opened` console log in my web console. If I remove the opacity property from the console, the popover displays.

My controller..

```
angular.module('search')

.controller('SearchResultsController', searchResultsController)

searchResultsController.$inject = ['$ionicPopover', '$scope'];

function searchResultsController($ionicPopover, $scope) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.openPopover = openPopover;

  activate();

  function activate( ) {
    $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('/templates/search/filter-popover.html', {
      scope: $scope
    }).then(function(popover) {
      console.log(popover)
      vm.popover = popover;
    });
  }

  function openPopover( $event ) {
    console.log("opened")
    vm.popover.show($event);
  }
}
```

My view page...

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
  <signed-in-header></signed-in-header>

  <ion-content class="padding has-header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-75 text-left">
        <div>4 RESULTS FOR "263355"</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col col-25 text-right">
        <div ng-click="searchResults.openPopover()">
          <i class="icon ion-arrow-down-b"></i>
          Filter
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>

  <ion-footer-bar>
    Ad here 1
  </ion-footer-bar>
</ion-view>
```

My popover template.

```
<ion-popover-view>
  <ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">My Popover Title</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    Hello!
  </ion-content>
</ion-popover-view>
```

Why does the popover not show and how can I fix this?

Comment: Same issue here. You come up with a solution?

Comment: In ng-click, you should pass $event parameter to the calling function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did some digging in the ionic CSS for popover, and the opacity is set to 0 by default.  You can override the opacity to 1 and the popover will display, but I found this:  https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2343.  Basically, you have to pass the event ($event) to popover.show() and it will work.  The ionic example shows this but the documentation could be more explicit.  In your code, change your template to ng-click="searchResults.openPopover($event)".

Answer (score 0):

In my case i just didn't put the popover component in the entryComponent section in my shared module. I didn’t get an error until I restarted the server, don't know why